# I want to know difference of calculation cost between SHA(hash) and AES(reversible encryption)

Tags: aes, hmac, sha-256

I want do detect illegal modification of a string by using HMAC-SHA256 or AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding, with low calculation cost.
Which is the best answer?

I plan to save data in a DB with one of the following format

```
| METHOD                   | original STRING | VALIDATION BY  |  
|--------------------------|-----------------|----------------|  
| H:= HMAC-SHA256          | org-string      | H(org-string)  |  
| A:= AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding | org-string      | A(org-string)  |
```

IF `A(org-string)` cannot be decrypted, the original STRING is modified.

FYI:
 [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990705/whats-the-difference-between-sha-and-aes-encryption) well explained difference between SHA and AES.

Comment: Note that you probably rather want [AES-CMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-key_MAC) than AES-CBC because only the former is meant to detect message manipulation.

Answer (score 2):

With AES/CBC mode, an attacker can modify the string, and have the result decrypt without errors; the only thing that can cause a decryption failure is an illegal padding pattern after decryption, and:

- If the plaintext string is at least 17 bytes long, then the attacker can modify the string without affecting the padding bytes (and thus leave a valid padding pattern)
- Alternatively, changing the entire ciphertext randomly leaves a 1/256 chance that, after decryption, the last byte of the ciphertext is 01 (which is a valid padding pattern)

Hence, to answer your question, HMAC-SHA256 is the best answer, as AES doesn't do the job at all.  If your crypto toolkit provides it, you might want to consider AES-CMAC instead (which is another right answer for this problem)